# The difference in appearance on Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, anaconda3

I have just used Jupyter for the first time. I installed it through Anaconda and managed to change the Jupyter notebook theme to avoid using the default white theme.

However, there was a slight difference between the appearance of my Jupyter and the one from the YouTuber I watched. Could this be due to version differences? How can I display the information tabs as marked in the line?

my jupyter notebook appearance
[image]

The Jupyter Notebook appearance that I desire
[image]

Comment: you seem to have the browser in dark mode. You can disable dark mode in the settings.

Answer (score 0):

from the menu 'view' click 'toggle toolbar'. then your toolbar should be visible (and reclick it if you want it to disappear)

Answer (score 0):

For removing the toolbar or header you could do from view menu, but the screenshot you show, it uses jupyter thems,
install:

```
pip install jupyterthemes
```

then enable :

```
jt -t onedork
```

it looks like that theme, but also you could checked other, list of them by

```
jt -l
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to this problem:

If you are using a theme other than the default one and cannot display the menu as shown in the marked image, revert the theme settings to default. In my case, the theme I was using seemed to have a bug, preventing me from using 'view' -> 'toggle toolbar'.

To reset your theme to the default theme, simply use the command:

```
jt -r
```

[image: Jupyter screenshot]